# Spring : @Repository annotation for DAO

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a RESTFul application with Spring 4.X.

In my DAO that calls a remote web service, I put `@Service` annotation.
But, in my recent researches I found the `@Repository` annotation that, [according to Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html), is suitable for DAOs :

> Teams implementing traditional J2EE patterns such as "Data Access
>   Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes, though care
>   should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access
>   Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so. This annotation is
>   a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their
>   semantics and use as appropriate.

My question is:

Is the Spring documentation referring to the DAO that persists data or DAO like mine that can call remote services? Which, in my case, is the most suitable annotation?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

you can use any stereotype like @Component also. According to my knowledge, These stereotype differ mainly by 'how they throw exception'. you can google exception thrown by different stereotype. This is why we use @Repository on DAO layer, @Service on Service layer, etc so that we can easily handle the exception.

This link will give you more Info. http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-component-service-repository-controller-difference/

***yes*, Spring documentation is referring to the DAOs that persist data. In your case, it depends on what type of services you are calling and how you want to handle the exception**. I would suggest to follow above suggested link.

Comment: Actually only `@Repository` annotation is a subject of specific exception translation. For more info about Spring exception hierarchy please refer to [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao)

Answer (score 1):

Reference -  [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)

> Spring provides further stereotype annotations: @Component, @Service, and @Controller. @Component is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component. @Repository, @Service, and @Controller are specializations of @Component for more specific use cases, for example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers, respectively. Therefore, you can annotate your component classes with @Component, but by annotating them with @Repository, @Service, or @Controller instead, your classes are more properly suited for processing by tools or associating with aspects. For example, these stereotype annotations make ideal targets for pointcuts. It is also possible that @Repository, @Service, and @Controller may carry additional semantics in future releases of the Spring Framework. Thus, if you are choosing between using @Component or @Service for your service layer, @Service is clearly the better choice. Similarly, as stated above, @Repository is already supported as a marker for automatic exception translation in your persistence layer.

**@Repository** -
This is to indicate that the class defines a data repository.